# How to change default widget for ALL NullBooleanFields to RadioSelect?

Tags: django, django-forms

Seems like there is an answer for how to do this for one NullBooleanField, but I have a ton of NullBooleanFields I want radio button style, so I want to do this DRY.

Comment: Have you tried a form mixin? and implement ``__init__`` to override the widget for a field given by its name

Comment: I will try this, and post a workaround if I can make one. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that in django-admin you may use the `formfield_overrides` option (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides).

However I don't think that you can do it in a normal `ModelForm` :(